# What is the best way to store time in DynamoDB when accuracy is important?

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, amazon-dynamodb, epoch

I am using AWS DynamoDB for storing time series data.

Accuracy is very important for this application. But, DynamoDB does not support native Date type to store.

I have two options:

1. Use UNIX Epoch Time
2. Use Date as string and store

Both options seem to have their problems:

The Epoch Time has the problem of leap seconds and losing accuracy.
The String Time type may have problems for sorting or querying between range of dates or times.

Which one should I use when accuracy is a key factor?

Comment: accuracy in the sense every second is accounted for and used to store data.

Answer (score 2):

Use ISO format.

- Stores milliseconds
- Stores an optional timezone
- Supports range queries for dates and date/time

Sample date formatted according to ISO 8601:

```
2016-12-02T00:52:34.256Z
```